# How to pass data from current fragment to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having 2 `Fragments` A and B. I am starting `Fragment B` from `Fragment A`. I need to pass data from `Fragment B` to `Fragment A` before `Fragment B` is closed. Its like `startActivityForResult()` idea.

Here in Fragment A I am calling Fragment B:

```
 FragmentB calendarDialog = new FragmentB();
                calendarDialog.setTargetFragment(CurrentPanchangDialog.this, 1);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
                transaction.add(android.R.id.content, calendarDialog).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Now in Fragment B I am calling something like this while closing:

```
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(
                    getTargetRequestCode(),
                    Activity.RESULT_OK,
                    new Intent().putExtra("data", "datafrom C")
            );
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

Now in the Base Activity I am overriding `onActivityForResult()`:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Fragment pFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
        if (pFragment instanceof CurrentPanchangDialog) {
            if (pFragment != null) {
                pFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

I am not getting the data back to Fragment A from Fragment B.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## **This method is also called the `Delegate Pattern`**

• Create an interface with one method like this one:

```
public interface FragmentCallback {
    void onDataSent(String yourData);
}
```

• Implement this interface in your FragmentA and implement onDataSent() method:

```
public class FragmentA implements FragmentCallback {

    @Override
    void onDataSent(String yourData){
        //Do something with your data
    }
}
```

• Declare this interface variable in Fragment B and create a public setter method:

```
public class FragmentB {

private FragmentCallback fragmentCallback;

    public void setFragmentCallback(FragmentCallback callback) {
        this.fragmentCallback = callback;
    }
}
```

• Somewhere withing FragmentA set it as a callback on FragmentB instance:

```
fragmentB.setFragmentCallback(this);
```

• Path data from FragmentB to FragmentA (you can do it from one of fragment's lifecycle method if data should be sent when FragmentB is about to be closed):

```
public class FragmentB {

    public void onDestroy() {
        if(fragmentCallback != null){
            fragmentCallback.onDataSent("Some data from FragmentB");
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: `fragmentB.setFragmentCallback(this);` where to call this in FragmentA? Please explain in detail

Comment: After FragmentB calendarDialog = new FragmentB(). You need an instance of FragmentB to call this, so after this line you can call it on calendarDialog.

Comment: I am not receiving any data. I am calling `fragmentCallback.onDataSent("Some data from FragmentB");` before `popBackStackImmediate()`

Comment: Hard to tell why it's not working whithout seeing your code. Make sure everything is implemented correctly - callback is implemented on FragmentA, but declared in FragmentB and called from FragmentB.

Comment: If I call from onDestroy() as you said. Its working fine. But if I call it before `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()` its not sending data.

Comment: Great! Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

You could alternatively just use a variable in the Activity, and then access it from the Fragment, maybe something like this:

Activity:

```
private String data;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public String getData() {
    return this.data;
}
```

Fragment:

```
String dataFromActivity = ((YourActivity)getActivity).getData();
```